# UIWebView - Autoresize so that no scrolling (in the webView itself) is needed

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uitextview, autoresize

I'm trying to use a `UIWebView` for displaying content higher than the screen of the iPhone, without needing to scroll in the `UIWebView` itself.

The `UIWebView` is placed as a subview to a `UIScrollView`, along with some other objects that I want the `UIScrollView` to scroll up and down *with* the `UIWebView`.

I know you can do this with a `UITextView` like this:

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame; frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height; _textView.frame = frame;
```

But the `UIWebView` does not inherit from `UIScrollView` and does therefore not contain the `contentSize`-property.

I'd really like to keep it a `UIWebView`, because the data I get is in HTML-blocks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the only way you'll be able to do this is to use some javascript to get the size of the web page and adjust the size of the UIWebView control.

Something like the following should do the trick

```
int content_height = [[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] integerValue];
CGRect rect = theWebView.frame;
rect.size.height = content_height;
theWebView.frame = rect;
```

You may need to add some sort of fudge factor to the content height.

Comment: Nope, this only seems to hide the UIWebView.. Good idea, though.

Comment: You might need to wait until the UIWebView has finished loading your content before the above code will give you what you want.  I have used a variation on the above code successfully in some web apps to resize embedded IFRAME tags.

Answer (score 14):

In fact, no Javascript is needed! 
In UIView there is a nice method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
```

You pass it anything (not really meaningful here), and it returns the size it'd like to be, using its content (subviews, etc) to compute the size.

Of course, since content loading in a UIWebView in asynchronous, you should do this after the webview has loaded, for instance in the UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGSize size = [webView sizeThatFits: CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)]; // Pass about any size
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = size.height;
    webView.frame = frame;
}
```

Et voila!

Comment: Specification: This did kind of work, but not when the webView contains images, probably because these aren't fully loaded at the time.

Comment: Ah... so UIWebView notify when the base HTML is loaded, not the whole page. Anyway, if your images change your layout, your pages are not W3C compliant (should contain size in the img tag) :p

Comment: Not my webpages ;) Thanks, though.

Comment: Seems like autolayout doesn't play nicely with resizing this way. In fact the UIWebView doesn't change in size at all. Is there something special to do for autolayout here?